# VUE data object get attribute/value

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, vuejs3

```
data() {
    return {
      Joke: {visible:true, ordering:1},
      Weather: {visible:true, ordering:3},
      Forecast: {visible:true, ordering:2},
      Nasa: {visible:true, ordering:4},
      Notes: {visible:true, ordering:5},
      Bored: {visible:true, ordering:6},
      
    };
},
```

When I try and loop through this and return each item:

```
for (var item in this.$data) {
    console.log(item[0]);
}
```

All I get is the name of the object rather than the data within.

I need to access the value of "ordering" for each of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (let item in this.$data) {
      console.log(this.$data[item]);
}
```

Please visit the MDN to review the usage of `for` and `in`.